# PHP not loading additional ini files in OS X with nginx

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite, mcrypt

I'm running OS X 10.10.03 and I'm having issues with mcrypt which was installed with home-brew via

```
homebrew install mcrypt
homebrew install php56-mcrypt
```

If I do php -i | grep mcrypt, it shows that mcrypt is working:

```
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
```

However, viewing phpinfo() in a browser doesn't indicate that mcrypt is working. It does point to the proper folder for additional ini files, but it doesn't load anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart apache service.

```
apachectl restart
```

Depending on your apache2 installation it may require running this with `sudo`. Homebrew apache installation does not require sudo in contrast to native OS X one.

Comment: I'm running nginx and php-fpm, both of which I restarted. I think I may just reinstall everything.

Comment: None of the answers provided there applied to my case. However, it did send me down a road in which I was able to figure it out. Somehow the symlink in my launch folder wasn't correct. Deleted it and relinked and then restarting nginx and php-fpm worked fine.